# extract password protected file in uwp

Tags: c#, passwords, zip, uwp

I'm working on a UWP-App in which I need to unzip a password protected file.

The zipfile-class in System.IO.Compression doesn't support a password protection and I didn't find any 3rd-party-library which can unzip in uwp.

So my question: Are there any possibilities to unzip a password-protected-zip-file in uwp?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the [ZLib.Portable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Zlib.Portable/) library, as this is a port of [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) which supported zip files with passwords!